# What adapter is needed to run a 1.8-inch notebook SSD in a desktop machine?

Tags: ssd, computer-building

I'm looking to upgrade a Lenovo ThinkPad X300 with a new SSD drive, to double its storage capacity.  I would like to take the old drive, which is a 1.8 inch SSD SATA drive, and use it in a desktop machine.  But I hear rumors that the power requirements may not be the same.  Do I need an adapter?  What is it called?  Where do I get it?  How will I know?

(I'm not worried about physically mounting the drive since luckily I have an Antec Solo and can just suspend the drive.  So correct power and connectors are my only issue.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.8" Sata Drives use Micro Sata. You can get an adapter to 2.5" Sata that will fit in pretty much any laptop or you can buy a further adapter to use it in a desktop.

I have seen a few in shops at very high prices, but, the best bet is probably eBay. A quick search found [this one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SSD-1-8-Inch-Micro-SATA-2-5-Hard-Drive-Caddy-Adapter-/180560699912?pt=PCC_Drives_Storage_Internal&hash=item2a0a41a208#ht_500wt_922) for about $20.

Comment: Brilliant.  Also http://www.amazon.com/Micro-SATA-Cables-2401510-MicroSATA/dp/B002P6PBAQ/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top